# How does Bitmoji work?

Tags: android, ios, 2d, morphing

does anyone have an idea, how bitmoji or other similar services work? I have an idea for an app, which should have custom Avatars.

There are multiple libraries for 3D-Games, which are based on Morphing. Easy. All the 2D-Characters however are seamingly made with sprites. But if you consider how many options bitmoji has, do you think, they basically have drawn all the possible sprites? Or am I to stupid to find the "yellow brick road"?

Thanks for any advice.